# Cannot plot cluster analysis without R having fatal error

Tags: r

I am pretty new to this language and am trying to carry out a cluster analysis using the hclust command.

When I try to plot the hclust R crashes with a fatal error and I need to start a new session. Any ideas whats causing this?

Cheers,

Z

```
setwd("~/Desktop/2")

WD<-getwd()

data <- read.table("CW2Data.txt", header = TRUE

data.nh <- data [,-c(1.1)]

data.mean <- apply(data.nh,2,mean)

data.sd <- apply(data.nh,2,sd)

data.scaled <- scale(data.nh,data.mean,data.sd)

data.dist <- dist(data.scaled)

data.hc <- hclust(data.dist)

plot(data.hc)
```

Comment: Exactly what error, and where does it get thrown?

Comment: It comes up in a box with a pic of a bomb and says 'R session Aborted. R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated.' And a button to start a new session

Comment: Then step through the code with a debugger, to find which line it breaks on.

Answer (score 1):

Add 'check = TRUE' to the plot argument, i.e. `plot(data.hc, check = TRUE)`
The  `hclust`  help says that this is the default value, but I found that adding it resolves this problem. The help documentation says:

*logical indicating if the x object should be checked for validity. This check is not necessary when x is known to be valid such as when it is the direct result of hclust(). The default is check=TRUE, as invalid inputs may crash R due to memory violation in the internal C plotting code.*

It would appear that the check is necessary even if the x object was generated by `hclust()`